# AngularJS how to handle route url changing and make broadcast

Tags: angularjs

How i can handle success route url changing, and then i should make a broadcast event to the new route url controller.

```js
$location.path('new_url');
 
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('openFunction', note);
    });
```

but current example isn't working, for me work example below:

```js
          $timeout(function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('openFunction', note);
            }, 300);
```

but it's wrong apporoach, to using timeout.

Comment: what is problem with current code..probably you need to apply digest cycle after doing `$location.path('new_url')`

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: How i can make  apply digest cycle ?? $scope.$apply?